# Days_Between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to ask how do i check if the difference between two dates.

1. BillingDate which is a date type with an entry 'DD-MON-YYYY'
2. and the other date is the current date.

> ```
> sys_date - BillingDate = daysFromBilled
> ```

alot of the examples i find they actually stated the second date to calculate the difference but what i am looking for is the difference between the current date so i can add it into a schedule or job.

i am using oracle btw.

---

Another point to add, i will continue to search, but if your could also recommend, how should i implement such a function:

1. Calculate date difference from all BillingDate entries
2. To trigger an alter table if the difference is more than 30 days to put Status as Late.
3. If Status is more than 60 days the Service attribute will be altered and changed to Cut

here is my rough table layout

```
Cust             Billing
--------         ----------
CustID(PK)       BillingID(PK)
LateStatus       LateStatus
Service          BillingDate
                 CustID
```

Thanks alot.

Update

REPLACE view DateDifference as 
select trunc(sysdate)- trunc(BillingDate)
from Billing;

seems legit.

Comment: An "alter table" is used to change the *definition* of a table (e.g. add or remove columns). You want to `UPDATE` the table, not "alter" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply subtract one date from the other:

```
BillingDate - sysdate
```

To do that in a select statement, just use it like this:

```
select billingdate - sysdate as daysFromBilled
from ...
```

Inside a trigger you use a regular assignment operator:

```
declare
    daysFromBilled integer;

begin 
    daysFromBilled := :new.billingdate - sysdate;
...
```

that will return the number of days, including fractional values if the time is different (a `DATE` column in Oracle also contains a time!).

If you only want to get full days, use this:

```
trunc(BillingDate) - trunc(sysdate)
```

---

This statement of yours:

> *date type with an entry 'DD-MON-YYYY'*

Indicates a misunderstanding on how `DATE` values work.

A `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) does ***not*** have any format.

They are stored in binary form in your column. The format is **only** applied when you display the value and thus convert it to a character literal. That is the work of the client application you use to display the values. SQL*Plus uses the NLS settings, other SQL tools might use a different configuration.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i understand the remarks about the update and alter table . i apologise if i ask stupid questions and statements, i am getting familiar with sql.  do you think you could show me an example of how you would write the syntax for the difference in days question.

Comment: @ChrisPin: I showed you how to calculate the difference in days.

Comment: @ChrisPin: Don't post code in comments, edit your question. And please read the Oracle manual regarding variable assignments in PL/SQL: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#i16001  See my edit for a short example.

Comment: thanks a_horse_with_no_name I really appreciate your help. thanks alot for the link too.

Answer (score 0):

All customers:

```
SELECT CUSTID
FROM BILLING
WHERE (SYSDATE - Billing_Date) >= 60
;
```

The following statement should update all the customer records where the difference is 60 days and over. Also, have added a clause to check if the service is already not set to CUT previously, so you don't end up updating the same records everytime.

```
UPDATE CUST_TABLE
SET SERVICE = 'CUT'
WHERE CustID in ( SELECT CustID
                   FROM BILLING_TABLE
                   WHERE (Sysdate - Billing_Date) >= 60
                 )
  AND NVL(SERVICE, 'X') != 'CUT'
;
```

Comment: You should avoid adding new answers if the question already has an accepted answer and you do not add any new piece of information (which where not present on the previous answers).